# Android XML shape style

Tags: android, xml, shapes, radio-group

I want to make a custom `RadioGroup` with shapes of my own.
I want the `android:checked="true"` to look like this:
[image]

Comment: ohhhhh kayyy...? So what's the problem?

Comment: @EmbattledSwag how do I style it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a `selector` in that case. I use this for `CheckBox`es, simply put the resulting XML file as `android:background`. This whould be an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_checked" />
  <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_unchecked" />
</selector>
```

Comment: I already have done this, the problem is: what is the content of `radio_checked`?

Comment: There's basically where you have to play around with your drawables in order to get the desired layout. As a drawable, you can set here any subclass of `Drawable` which includes: `BitmapDrawable, ClipDrawable, ColorDrawable, DrawableContainer, GradientDrawable, InsetDrawable, LayerDrawable, NinePatchDrawable, PictureDrawable, RotateDrawable, ScaleDrawable, ShapeDrawable`. Of course it might be even another XML layout file if you need to define your own drawable.